# What is the difference between Aperture and Adobe Lightroom?

Tags: macos, adobe-lightroom, aperture

In terms of user experience, handling, expandability (support for third-party plugins such as Photomatix), ability to seamlessly publish to Flickr/Picasa etc?

Apple has a temporary action - buy an iMac and get E75 gift at app store. Aperture cost some E65 so I thought to maybe give it a try.

Is Aperture worth it?

Answer (score 2):

Aperture is for OS X only. Lightroom is available for both Windows and OS X. Both perform the same basic cataloging although with different approaches.  If you plan on making photo books, Aperture is very good. Lightroom has better noise reduction and has a slight advantage in image adjustment. This will probably flip on the next Aperture release, competition is good.

As commented above, Aperture plugin support is better.

What are your friends/co-workers using? If you don't have some contacts using Aperture, you will probably find that support/training/help is easier to find for Lightroom.

Answer (score 1):

Aperture is a lab that employs various psychotic and sentient robo-personalities to perform various forms of stress testing upon human subjects, willingly or unwillingly. All human subjects are given a rather unique piece of equipment that allows them to create wormhole-connected portals on certain surfaces. This unexpected behavior is considered highly irregular to most human minds and so the tests, which physically stressing, are almost completely mentally exhausting 100% of the time.

Subjects are goaded on by promise of cake, which is a lie.

The Aperture labs are run by pan-dimensional beings which in our physical world appear to resemble mice.

Lightroom is their competitor who, for lack of a suitably mind-bending tool and psychoticly sentient systems, failed to garner a contract with Valve.

Comment: So full of win.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a 30-day trial of Aperture here: http://www.apple.com/aperture/trial/.  Aperture supports a host of different plugins.  You can get an idea over here: 
http://www.apple.com/aperture/resources/plugins.html.

If the basis of buying the Mac revolves around Aperture, you may want to visit an Apple Store or another retailer and see if they have a copy of Aperture to play around with.